# Can't seem to use a hyphen in my environment variables in my docker command

Tags: docker

I have the following bash command that is running on my CI server:

```
ssh -i ./id_rsa ec2-user@$test_instance -- docker run --net host --rm -i \
  -v /home/ec2-user/my_project:/build -w /build node:12.13.0 \
  -e REACT_APP_API_KEY=abc-def \
  npm run start:remoteserver
```

I get an error saying unexpected token on the characters `def`. I've tried using the other flags or putting the api key in quotes but it still isn't working. Why is this happening and what can I do to successfully supply it?

Comment: Move the `-e REACT_APP_API_KEY=...` option before the image name `node:12.13.0`.

Comment: doh, I can accept an answer if you post it